# Select from hash array based on values from other array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have these arrays. And i want to select only the instances with the `:teacher` value from the `@teachers` array and put them in `@filtered_courses`.

```
@teachers = ["KAP", "CWD"]
@courses = [
  {:gruppnamn=>"ESM15/15MUSINS01Str", :kurskod=>"MUSINS01S", :teacher=>"MWN", :class=>"ESM15", :points=>100.0, :kvot=>nil, :tim=>nil},
  {:gruppnamn=>"ESM15/15MUSMUS01", :kurskod=>"MUSMUS01", :teacher=>"KAP", :class=>"ESM15", :points=>100.0, :kvot=>nil, :tim=>nil},
  {:gruppnamn=>"Hälsostudion/15år2", :kurskod=>"IDRIDR01", :teacher=>"CWD", :class=>"ESSA", :points=>100.0, :kvot=>nil, :tim=>nil}
]
```

Comment: The method to select certain elements from an array is called [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
@filtered_courses = @courses.select { |x| @teachers.include? x[:teacher] }
# => [{:gruppnamn=>"ESM15/15MUSMUS01", :kurskod=>"MUSMUS01", :teacher=>"KAP", :class=>"ESM15", :points=>100.0, :kvot=>nil, :tim=>nil},
#     {:gruppnamn=>"Hlsostudion/15r2", :kurskod=>"IDRIDR01", :teacher=>"CWD", :class=>"ESSA", :points=>100.0, :kvot=>nil, :tim=>nil}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved it!